# jupiterlab how to install @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to run panel in jupiter lab,
However the graphs are not interactive.

I found that i need to `[install this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz), however i am unable to install it, i have tried:

```py
npm i @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz

out: 

  File "<ipython-input-21-385fb6412a4c>", line 1
    npm i @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This one:

```py
# as found https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/index.html
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
jupyter labextension install @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz

Out: 
  File "<ipython-input-22-e086b2168729>", line 1
    conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and finally:

```py
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab_pyviz

OUT: 
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - jupyterlab_pyviz

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just released pyviz_comms 2.0 which automatically bundles the JupyterLab extension. Simply upgrade with pip install pyviz_comms --upgrade or conda install -c pyviz pyviz_comms.